# Can't I use the :first-child selector in this scenario?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

My [code](http://jsfiddle.net/NdYuD/) :

```
<div class="allegati-item">
    <div class="allegati-titolo">Download</div>
    <a class="allegati-link" href="/documenti/DocumentoTest.pdf">Link1</a>
    <a class="allegati-link" href="/documenti/DocumentoTest.pdf">Link2</a>
</div>

.allegati-link
{
    border-top:1px solid #FF0000;
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:4px;
}

.allegati-item a.allegati-link:first-child
{
    border:0;
}​
```

I want to delete border in the first `allegati-link` element, but since there is a div before it, inside the `allegati-item`, seems this can't be possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this instead:

```
.allegati-item .allegati-titolo + a.allegati-link{
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `:first-of-type` instead or

```
.allegati-item > .allegati-titolo + a
```

The last version has slightly better browser support (from IE7 on) while the first one is less dependent on your markup.

Comment: @RobW Not all, `:nth-of-type(1)` is missed )

Comment: @Engineer I omitted this, since there is obviously no need for;) You might as well get fancy with the selectors.

Comment: @Christoph Yeah, like e.g. `:nth-of-type(0n+1)` this.

Answer (score 2):

premising that `:first-of-type` is probably the best choice, here's another alternative for browser that doesn't support yet that pseudoclass

```
.allegati-link { border: 0; }
.allegati-link + .allegati-link { border-top: ...}
```

doing so you will remove the border only from the first link .

Answer (score 0):

You can this also

```
$(".allegati-titolo").next().attr("style", "border-top:0px; display:block; margin-bottom:4px;");
```

This will first select next element of div having class="allegati-titolo" and then apply the style to the 1st link.

Comment: +1: It's not CSS, but using JS for this isn't such a bad idea since CSS3 selectors are not supported in IE<9.

Comment: @JezenThomas css3 is not strictly necessary here. adjacent selector `+` is part of css 2.1 and it is supported even by IE7 :)